# How to save input from actionlistener, and then compare to another in Java?

Tags: java, jframe, actionlistener

I am making a rock-paper-scissors game, where 2 players have to choose if they are going to use rock, paper or scissors. And then my program is suposed to compare the the choices. But I'm having problems saving the choices as a variable. 
I can print out the the choices, but I don't know how I can use the answers outside the actionlisteneres.

So this is the code I have(some of the names are in Norwegian, so might be a bit confusing, but hopefully you understand):

```
package oblig8;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Oblig8 extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
JFrame Frame = new JFrame("Stein - Saks - Papir");
Frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
Frame.setSize(500, 500);
Frame.setVisible(true);
JButton Spiller1 = new JButton("Spiller 1");
JButton Spiller2 = new JButton("Spiller 2");
Frame.getContentPane().add(Spiller1, BorderLayout.WEST);
Frame.getContentPane().add(Spiller2, BorderLayout.EAST);
String[] muligheter = new String[3];
muligheter[0]="Stein";
muligheter[1]="Saks";
muligheter[2]="Papir";

Spiller1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          int valg1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Frame,
                  "Spiller 1 har trykket",
                  "Stein - Saks - Papir",
                  JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                  JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                  null,
                  muligheter,
                  muligheter[2]);
          System.out.println(valg1);}});
Spiller2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      int valg2 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Frame,
              "Spiller 2 har trykket",
              "Stein - Saks - Papir",
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
              JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
              null,
              muligheter,
              muligheter[2]);
      System.out.println(valg2);}});
}}
```

Comment: You should follow the the convention of using variable names that start with lower case letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare static int variables in the class scope, and store the answer in these variable, then used it as you wish

```
public class Oblig8 extends JFrame {

static int valg1;
static int valg2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...

    Spiller1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            valg1 = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(Frame,
                    "Spiller 1 har trykket",
                    "Stein - Saks - Papir",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    muligheter,
                    muligheter[2]);
            System.out.println(valg1);
        }
    });
    ...
}
}
```

Comment: This is certainly a quick way to get something up and running, but it's almost certainly not the right way to proceed. Avoid global variables where you can, and store them as instance fields. (Think about what would happen if you wanted two windows open at the same time, for example.)

Comment: @chiastic-security yea, agree, it is not a good design. To achieve a better design, I would create my own JFrame or JPanel class with fields holding the selected choices, and extract the logic in the actionPerformed() method to a separate method so that the logic is not bounded to the anonymous class. Let's see what the OP has to say:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your `main` method to create an instance of the `Oblig8` class, and then use that as the `JFrame`. Once you've done this, the rest of your code can be moved to instance methods of that class.

Your `ActionListener`s will then be running inside instances of your `Oblig8` class, and they'll have access to its fields and methods. They'll be able to write to instance fields, and also to invoke instance methods to get further things to happen.

So your `main` method can be very short:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Oblig8 oblig8 = new Oblig8();
    oblig8.doSomeStuff();
}
```

All your other code can then be moved into the `Oblig8` constructor, or its `doSomeStuff` method.

Add some fields to your `Oblig8` class, and then get your `ActionListener`s to interact with them.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the anonymous class, which does not store the value to be accessed later. Since these methods are basically the same it seems just efficient to go ahead and create a proper nested subclass.

```
static class SpillerButton extends JButton implements ActionListener {
   int valg;

   SpillerButton(String name){
      super(name);
      addActionListener(this);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      valg = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
              getText()+"har trykket",
              "Stein - Saks - Papir",
              JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
              JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
              null,
              muligheter,
              muligheter[2]);
     System.out.println(valg);
  }
}
```

And `muligheter` should probably be a `final static` constant in `Oblig8` anyway, but it needs to be where this subclass can find it.

Now instead of using generic `JButton`s you use `SpillerButton`s and get the value whenever you want to show the results.